# Can we recover the sheaf from the functor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $S$ be a scheme of finite type over $k$. Let $\mathrm{Sch}/S$ be the category of schemes of **finite type** over $S$. Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf on $S$. Consider the following functor
$$
  \mathbf{Dual}_{\mathcal F}:(\mathrm{Sch}/S)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set},\quad \big[f:T\to S\big]\mapsto \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal O_T}(f^*\mathcal F,\mathcal O_T)
$$
where the functor on morphisms is naturally defined.

We can recover the dual $\mathcal F^\vee:=\mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_S}(\mathcal F,\mathcal O_S)$ from $\mathbf{Dual}_{\mathcal F}$ by looking at open subsets $[U\subset S]\in\mathrm{Sch}/S$. However more is encoded in the functor. For example, if $S=\mathbb A^1$ and $\mathcal F$ is the skyscraper sheaf at the origin, then $\mathcal F^\vee=0$ and $\mathbf{Dual}_{\mathcal F}(0\hookrightarrow \mathbb A^1)\cong k$.

I want to ask

> To what extent can we recover $\mathcal F$ from $\mathbf{Dual}_{\mathcal F}$?

A more specific question that I am interested in currently is

> Can we characterise $\mathcal F$ being locally free in terms of $\mathbf{Dual}_{\mathcal F}$?

Comment: That is actually a functor to $\mathbb{A}^1_S$-modules that is representable by an affine morphism over $S$ with an action of $\mathbb{A}^1_S$.  The pushforward of the structure sheaf is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-module with an action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ (inherited from the structure of $\mathbb{A}^1$-module).  The first nontrivial $\mathbb{G}_m$-eigensheaf of the pushforward of the structure sheaf equals $\mathcal{F}$.  The coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free if and only if the affine morphism to $S$ is flat.

Comment: @JasonStarr I do not understand you. If I consider $S=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $T=\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ and $f:T\to S$ corresponding to $A\to B$, then the pushforward of the structure sheaf is $B$, as an $A$-module with an action of $\mathbb G_m$?

Comment: Push forward the structure sheaf for the affine morphism that represents the functor.  You will get the symmetric algebra on $\mathcal{F}$ with its standard grading corresponding to the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$.  The first nontrivial eigensheaf is just the first graded piece of the symmetric algebra, which equals $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Isn't the functor you are studying represented by $\mathcal{Spec}_S(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathcal{F}))$? This is the relativised "Spec" construction over $S$ applied to the sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_S$ algebras given by the sum of symmetric powers of $\mathcal{S}$.. OK I just realised that Jason Starr already said this!

Comment: @Kapil Yes, I just realized this after Jason's comments.

Comment: The question is about $\mathbf{Dual}_F$ as a set-valued functor, while Jason's construction uses the natural $\mathbb{A}^1$-module structure on it.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly. Of course you are correct.  To answer the two questions out of order: the coherent sheaf is locally free if and only if the morphism is flat.  When the morphism is flat, we can recover the sheaf as the pullback to the base with respect to any section ( and these exist) of the sheaf of relative differentials.

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting my final comment as one answer.  The set-valued functor $\textbf{Dual}_{\mathcal{F}}$ is representable by an affine $S$-scheme that is canonically isomorphic to the relative Spec over $S$ of the quasi-coherent sheaf of graded $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras, $$\bigoplus_{d\geq 0} \text{Sym}^d_{\mathcal{O}_S} \left(\mathcal{F}\right).$$  In particular, the sheaf of relative differentials over $S$ for this affine $S$-scheme is canonically isomorphic to the pullback of $\mathcal{F}$.  Thus, for every section over $S$ of the affine $S$-scheme, the pullback of the sheaf of relative differentials is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$.  Of course there are sections, e.g., the zero section corresponding to the zero homomorphism from $\mathcal{F}$ to the structure sheaf.

Comment: would you please explain the connection to the sheaf of relative differentials?

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal For a scheme $S$ and a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules $\mathcal{F}$, for the relative Spec $S$-scheme associated to the quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras as above, the sheaf of relative differentials is canonically isomorphic to the pullback from $S$ of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: thank you. Can you point me to a reference for this fact? I haven't found it stated so cleanly anywhere.

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal It is formula 1.1.3.2 on p. 118 of "Complexe cotangent et d'eformations, I" by Luc Illusie.